# Hive collect struct type

Tags: hive, group-by, collect

I have a hive table:

```
id  name         address               cid
1   ABC {"city":"Tampa","state":"FL"}   1
2   XYZ {"city":"SF","state":"CA"}      1
```

Wanted to group by based on cid and get:

```
                address                                  cid
{"city":"Tampa","state":"FL"}{"city":"SF","state":"CA"}   1
```

I tried collect_set and collect_list but they both only work with primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

A fast way to achieve this is to select struct fields as separate columns then use the approach described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385425/hive-select-data-into-an-array-of-structs) (it requires Brickhouse third-party UDFs)