# How to insert data into array of Struct in Hive

Tags: arrays, struct, hive

I need to create an array of struct in Hive so that for one ID, I can put multiple structs in an array of struct.

I have created below table

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tbl1
(
sess_id STRING
, source_start_ts STRING
, source_end_ts STRING
,Node_String STRUCT < Node: STRING, Time_Spent:STRING, 
Txn_Type: STRING, Txn_Status: STRING, Call_Status: STRING >
)
 STORED AS ORC
```

and then created second table which has array of above struct (I could have array of struct on the first table, but I tried that too and failed)

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tbl2
(
 sess_id STRING
,Col2 Array<STRUCT < Node: STRING, 
Time_Spent:STRING, Txn_Type: STRING, Txn_Status: STRING, 
Call_Status: STRING >>
) STORED AS ORC
```

However, when using below collect_set to populate it, I get an error

```
insert into table tbl2
select sess_id
, collect_set(Node_String) as Col2
from tbl1
where sess_id = 'abc'
group by sess_id
```

here is the error

> SQL Error [40000] [42000]: Error while compiling statement: FAILED:
>   UDFArgumentTypeException Only primitive type arguments are accepted
>   but
>   struct
>   was passed as parameter 1.

I guess collect_set does not accept struct type. Is there any function that does this?

Here is an example

```
id, source_start_dt, source_end_dt, Node_string
1,'2019-01-01','2019-01-02' , {"node1","10s","activation", "123", "failed"}
1,'2019-01-01','2019-01-02', {"node2","120s","activation", "123", "Logged"}
1,'2019-01-01','2019-01-02', {"node3","450s","activation", "123", "completed"}
```

As you can see above, there are multiple Node_String with different struct fields for each ID. ID '1' has 3 rows and in order to roll those three row up in one, I used collect_set

Thanks

Comment: can you show some sample data and the reasoning behind using `collect_set`?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala thanks. Take a look at example.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember CollectUDAF of [brickhouse](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse) can work with both primitive and complex types like structs. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385425/hive-select-data-into-an-array-of-structs).